# Vlookup formula to return a result which may not be the first instance

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have a sheet that automatically imports data from an external source in a somewhat similiar format to the below. I'm trying to retrieve the sales person associated to a certain ID into another table.
I've been trying to use a Vlookup but it only retrieves the first result which it finds which is often the blank.

| List | client ID | Sales Person |
| --- | --- | --- |
| delivery | 124564 |  |
| delivery | 124564 | Gemma |
| Scoping | 56787 | Timothy |
| Scoping | 56787 |  |
| Scoping |  |  |
| Lost |  |  |
| Lost | 43978 | Harry |
| Lost | 43978 |  |

I have another Vlookup reference table where I have the Id's and Sales Persons organised to reference such as the below.

| client ID | Sales Person |
| --- | --- |
| 124564 | Gemma |
| 56787 | Timothy |
| 43978 | Harry |

the table im trying to work the formula into looks something like the below.

| client ID | Sales Person |
| --- | --- |
| 124564 | =vlookup(client ID,List:Sales Person,3,FALSE) |
| 56787 |  |
| 43978 |  |

I'm not sure if I've worded this well at all, but im essentially trying to return the name of the sales person when they may be the third or fourth value in the table with the same reference item..

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
=map(F2:F,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,iferror(+tocol(filter(C:C,B:B=Σ),1)))))
```

[image]